# Magento newsletter not posting

Tags: magento

I wish to have a newsletter on my home page. I found the following code, which I have copied into my "Content" tab.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

This is rendered on my page, however I cannot find the response. That is, the receipts are not entered into the newsletter section. It doesn't seem to post anywhere. Here is the HTML produced.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail"> 
    <div class="block-content"> 
        <label for="newsletter">Sign Up for Our Newsletter:</label> 
        <div class="input-box"> 
           <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="Sign up for our newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" /> 
        </div> 
        <div class="actions"> 
            <button type="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button"><span><span>Subscribe</span></span></button> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `newsletter/subscribe` as you block type because `core/template` doesn't have `getFormActionUrl()` method, which returns url for submitting newsletter subscription form.

Use this code inside of your CMS page:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: thanks spot on!! this works though it just redirects back to the original page. Is there away for me to append a querystring or something so that i can write a thank you message. ie ?success=true