# Magento newsletter not subscribing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, newsletter

I have moved the newsletter subscription box to the footer. When I try to subscribe, the page reloads and adds this to the url: ?email=test%40test.nl (in case of using the test@test.nl adress)

The changes I made where in the newsletter.xml (to move the block to the footer) and footer.phtml (to echo the block in the footer).

Tried the solution in this question already: [Magento newsletter not posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382850/magento-newsletter-not-posting)
But did nothing. ALso tried to change this:getFormActionUrl() ?> to the direct url, same result.

Anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the actual URL you're experiencing this on?  It would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, was actually a very dumb mistake by me...

The subscribe block was also wrapped in another  so it didn't post. So the anwser was a combination of above anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the newsletter.xml this way from:

```
    <default>

    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

to:

```
   <default> 
    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

And the newsletter box displays in the footer, submit works. There is no need to add "echo" to footer.phtml.